# 403 error loading static files in Bitnami @ google cloud for Django website Apache

Tags: django, apache, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, bitnami

Save me from Apache insanity.
I have a Django site deployed in google cloud using Bitnami (Apache) and the templates load okay. The static files however return:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

The **httpd-app.conf** is as below:

```
<IfDefine !IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED>
    Define IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED
    WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-djangostack   processes=2 threads=15    display-name=%{GROUP}
</IfDefine>

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/project/project">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-djangostack

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Directory>

Alias /static/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/project/static"
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/project/static>
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /project '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/project/project/wsgi.py'
```

the collected static is at **/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/project/static**

i have tried every solution i have found, first i added

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/project/static>
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

in httpd.conf in apache  ... didnt work

I then set permissions to project directory by:

```
sudo chmod 775 /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django-projets/project
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django-projets/project
```

it didnt work either. Followed by a couple more which were basically somehow similar to this two.

Thanks

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Thanks for using Bitnami, these two sections of our documentation explains how to [create](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/get-started/start-django-project/) and [deploy](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/) a custom Django project. Does you application work when using its standalone port?

Comment: hi i did go through the steps but i still get a 403 error and yeah it does work in localhost

Comment: I just followed our documentation and it seems that there are some steps or changes in the configuration files that don't match with the reality when creating a new Django project. That could be the cause of the issues you are running into. Our team will investigate that and will let you know once we update our documentation.

Comment: We re-checked the guide and verified it is correct. It seems you are facing one of the following issues: (a) The static directory is empty (b) The static directory is not created (c) You are accessing the static directory without specifying any file. These issues can be fixed running "mkdir static && cd static && touch test". After that, access http://localhost/arbspiper/static/test and you should see an empty result. Hope it helps!

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I am no longer continuing with the path of deploying to gcloud. I'll run a test to see the mistake i may have made. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue by adding 777 permission to the entire directory for the site.
chmod -R 777 *directory name*

[This tutorial was of great help](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/get-started-bitnami-django)

Comment: The above given tutorial is helpful but still I am sure people will have issue regarding loading of static resources because Bitnami django stack currently supports Django 2.2.5 and Python version 3.7 but the tutorial is in context of earlier Django and Python versions. So those who are new I suggest they should change the versions in the "conf" files as per their version.